# Laravel Upsert works well on MySQL but not on Postgresql

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I have a schema to create a table for mobile money transactions as follows.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('mobile_money_statements', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary()->index();
            $table->uuid('user_id')->index();
            $table->integer("total_pages")->unsigned();
            $table->integer("total_transactions")->unsigned();
            $table->integer("opening_balance")->unsigned();
            $table->integer("closing_balance")->unsigned();
            $table->string("service_provider");
            $table->string("phone_number")->unique();
            $table->string("account_holder_name");
            $table->integer("debit_turnover")->unsigned();
            $table->integer("credit_turnover")->unsigned();
            $table->datetime("date_created");
            $table->datetime("from_date")->unique();
            $table->datetime("to_date")->unique();
            $table->datetime("date_last_balance");
            $table->integer("last_balance")->unsigned();

            $table->timestamps();
        });
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE mobile_money_statements ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4();');


    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('mobile_money_statements');
    }
};
```

And a mobile money statement model as follows.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUuids;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;


class MobileMoneyStatement extends Model
{
    use HasUuids;
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'total_pages',
        'opening_balance',
        'closing_balance',
        'service_provider',
        'phone_number',
        'account_holder_name',
        'debit_turnover',
        'credit_turnover',
        'date_created',
        'from_date',
        'to_date',
        'date_last_balance',
        'last_balance'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'date_created' => 'datetime',
        'from_date' => 'datetime',
        'to_date' => 'datetime',
        'date_last_balance' => 'datetime',
        'id' => 'string'

    ];

    public $incrementing = false;
    /**
     * Get the transactions associated with the statement.
     */
    public function transaction()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MobileMoneyTransaction::class)->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class)->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    }

    /**
     * Interacts with opening balance.
     *
     * @return Attribute
     */
    protected function openingBalance(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn ($value) => round($value / 100.00,2),
                 set: fn ($value) => intval($value * 100),
        )->shouldCache();
    }

    /**
     * Interacts with closing balance.
     *
     * @return Attribute
     */
    protected function closingBalance(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn ($value) => round($value / 100.00,2),
                 set: fn ($value) => intval($value * 100),
        )->shouldCache();
    }

    /**
     * Interacts with debit turnover.
     *
     * @return Attribute
     */
    protected function debitTurnover(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn ($value) => round($value / 100.00,2),
                 set: fn ($value) => intval($value * 100),
        )->shouldCache();
    }


    /**
     * Interacts with credit turnover.
     *
     * @return Attribute
     */
    protected function creditTurnover(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn ($value) => round($value / 100.00,2),
                 set: fn ($value) => intval($value * 100),
        )->shouldCache();
    }

    /**
     * Interacts with last balance.
     *
     * @return Attribute
     */
    protected function lastBalance(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn ($value) => round($value / 100.00,2),
                 set: fn ($value) => intval($value * 100),
        )->shouldCache();
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to do an upsert on the mobile money statements model, that is to create if it does not exist and to update if it does.

```
       $dbStatement = MobileMoneyStatement::upsert(
            [
                'id'    => $statementId,
                'user_id' => User::first()->id,
                'total_pages'   => $statement->getTotalPages(),
                'total_transactions'   => $statement->getTotalTransactions(),
                'opening_balance'   => $statement->getOpeningBalance(),
                'closing_balance'   => $statement->getClosingBalance(),
                'service_provider'  => $statement->getServiceProvider(),
                'phone_number'  =>  $statement->getPhoneNumber(),
                'account_holder_name'   => $statement->getAccountHolderName(),
                'debit_turnover'    =>  $statement->getDebitTurnover(),
                'credit_turnover'   =>  $statement->getCreditTurnover(),
                'date_created'  =>  $statement->getDateCreated(),
                'from_date' =>  $statement->getFromDate()->format('Y-m-d'),
                'to_date'   => $statement->getToDate()->format('Y-m-d'),
                'date_last_balance' =>  $statement->getDateLastBalance(),
                'last_balance'  =>  $statement->getLastBalance()
            ],
            [
                'user_id' => User::first()->id,
                'phone_number' => $statement->getPhoneNumber(),
                'from_date' => $statement->getFromDate()->format('Y-m-d'),
                'to_date' => $statement->getToDate()->format('Y-m-d'),
            ]
        );
```

This is already working on MySQL but when I changed database to use postgresql on laravel, this code for upsert is throwing a database exception as follows.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column &quot;8ac921b3-a18a-468a-8b09-44c7ea015266&quot; does not exist
LINE 1: ...1, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18) on conflict (&quot;8ac921b3...
                                                             ^ (SQL: insert into &quot;mobile_money_statements&quot; (&quot;account_holder_name&quot;, &quot;closing_balance&quot;, &quot;created_at&quot;, &quot;credit_turnover&quot;, &quot;date_created&quot;, &quot;date_last_balance&quot;, &quot;debit_turnover&quot;, &quot;from_date&quot;, &quot;id&quot;, &quot;last_balance&quot;, &quot;opening_balance&quot;, &quot;phone_number&quot;, &quot;service_provider&quot;, &quot;to_date&quot;, &quot;total_pages&quot;, &quot;total_transactions&quot;, &quot;updated_at&quot;, &quot;user_id&quot;) values (EMMANUEL JEAN KAMASAH, 0, 2023-08-01 12:09:49, 134207.55, 2022-10-24 00:46:16, 2022-10-22 19:41:27, 116737.02, 2021-01-01, 99c92471-31f1-4603-acfd-605f27b2a5da, 0, 32.32, 233551097252, MTN GH, 2022-10-22, 109, 1534, 2023-08-01 12:09:49, 8ac921b3-a18a-468a-8b09-44c7ea015266) on conflict (&quot;8ac921b3-a18a-468a-8b09-44c7ea015266&quot;, &quot;233551097252&quot;, &quot;2021-01-01&quot;, &quot;2022-10-22&quot;) do update set &quot;id&quot; = &quot;excluded&quot;.&quot;id&quot;, &quot;user_id&quot; = &quot;excluded&quot;.&quot;user_id&quot;, &quot;total_pages&quot; = &quot;excluded&quot;.&quot;total_pages&quot;, &quot;total_transactions&quot; = &quot;excluded&quot;.&quot;total_transactions&quot;, &quot;opening_balance&quot; = &quot;excluded&quot;.&quot;opening_balance&quot;, &quot;closing_balance&quot; = &quot;excluded&quot;.&quot;closing_balance&quot;, &quot;service_provider&quot; = &quot;excluded&quot;.&quot;service_provider&quot;, &quot;phone_number&quot; = &quot;excluded&quot;.&quot;phone_number&quot;, &quot;account_holder_name&quot; = &quot;excluded&quot;.&quot;account_holder_name&quot;, &quot;debit_turnover&quot; = &quot;excluded&quot;.&quot;debit_turnover&quot;, &quot;credit_turnover&quot; = &quot;excluded&quot;.&quot;credit_turnover&quot;, &quot;date_created&quot; = &quot;excluded&quot;.&quot;date_created&quot;, &quot;from_date&quot; = &quot;excluded&quot;.&quot;from_date&quot;, &quot;to_date&quot; = &quot;excluded&quot;.&quot;to_date&quot;, &quot;date_last_balance&quot; = &quot;excluded&quot;.&quot;date_last_balance&quot;, &quot;last_balance&quot; = &quot;excluded&quot;.&quot;last_balance&quot;, &quot;updated_at&quot; = &quot;excluded&quot;.&quot;updated_at&quot;) in file C:\Users\EmmanuelKamasah\Projects\PHP\lendsignals\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 760
```

I do not understand why this is happening on postgresql.
thanks in advance.

Comment: The entire piece of SQL is not valid, columns have something that looks like a quote and values don’t have any quotes. Even without the on conflict this is not going to work

Comment: The sql returned is not what I am sending to the server but the response from postman when I run a query

Comment: `Undefined column` is a common error message when there is something wrong with the quotes in your SQL statement. Check your query log and focus on the quotes. I'm not a PHP developer, can't help you with Laravel

Comment: I am not writing any plain SQL but is using Laravel orm, the statement that is producing the SQL is the MobileMoneyStatement::upsert([......}). it is not a SQL issue as this same code was working on MYSQL database but won't work on PostgreSQL, I switched to PostgreSQL because I want to use vector embeddings with pgvector

Comment: You are mixing `updateOrCreate()` and `upsert()` syntaxes.

Answer (score 2):

I think second param should be not value, but field for conflict check.

Something like this:

```
MobileMoneyStatement::upsert([...], ['user_id','phone_number','from_date','to_date']);
```

Comment: This does not work

Comment: @JeanLinux It should because that's what the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#upserts) says. And even if it doesn't work, the error message should be different.

Comment: Is there different error? Can you show me? @Olivier is right, it's from documentation.